# What formula can be used to find unique value in two data in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to find two unique names in two data. Could you kindly advise what formula can be used?  Thank you so much

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lkLSmrbln3ZIZSIe25A48nH6931LzQ8DnLmfI_3jsMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(A2:B), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"),
 "select Col1 where Col2 = 1")
```

[image]